# PHP: For loop is done before the code is executed

Tags: php, for-loop, indexing, echo

I'm having a problem with php's for loop.
The loop iterates too fast and is done before the html code inside is echo-ed.

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($shoppingCart); $i++) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products_test WHERE id = " . substr($shoppingCart[$i], 5) . "";
    $q = $DBH->query($sql) or die("failed!");
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $r = $q->fetchAll();
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><img src="' . $r[$i]['image']. '" /></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $r[$i]['title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $r[$i]['desc'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $r[$i]['price'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="number" id="qty"></td>';
    echo '<td>Remove</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
} ?>
```

Setting a temporary variable won't work because it will just have the same behaviour.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what s wrong? what is your expected result and what r u getting now?

Comment: What do you mean by "done before the html code inside is echo-ed"?  Sounds like you're getting an error, so the code stops.

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact code, and there is not a `;` after `$i++);`

Comment: And what are the contents of `$shppingCart`?

Comment: @Michael: You mean in the `for` loop?  You don't put a `;` after the `$i++` in the `for` loop.

Comment: @Rocket no, I mean after the for loop's closing `)` which executes it before the subsequent code.

Comment: @Michael: Ah, I see what you're asking.  Never mind.

Comment: Before the loop, put
    print "<pre>";
    print_r(shoppingCart);
    print "</pre>";
What is the output?

Comment: what is the expected value of $shoppingCart[$i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your array is coming up empty. You should add a catch in case.

You would want to make something like this, using the `empty` function:

```
<?php 
 if (!empty($shoppingCart))
 {
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($shoppingCart); $i++) { 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM products_test WHERE id = " . substr($shoppingCart[$i], 5) . "";
     $q = $DBH->query($sql) or die("failed!");
     $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $r = $q->fetchAll();
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td><img src="' . $r[$i]['image']. '" /></td>';
     echo '<td>' . $r[$i]['title'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $r[$i]['desc'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $r[$i]['price'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td><input type="number" id="qty"></td>';
     echo '<td>Remove</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
  } 
 }
 else
 {
     echo '<tr><td>Your shopping cart is empty</td></tr>';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that your query always returns one row? But you try to access non-existent rows with `$r[$i]`.

This would explain, why you can't see anything in the browser. But try to view the browser source code, if it displays empty html tags, then it's this problem.

Try to display the contents of your array with `print_r($r)` and see how this looks like.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem. Sorry for not providing any more information.